# In French, how do you express "measly" in "just a measly one pair"?

Tags: choix-de-mot

> Your current hand in five-card poker is disappointingly unglamorous with just a **[measly](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/measly?q=measly%2B)** one pair.

The adjective "measly" is used here to emphasise that One Pair is considered **low(est) in value** as a poker hand.

In saying this phrase, the following three adjectives come to mind, but I find myself wavering between them, as these synonymous words ought to have shades of meaning that make one of them more appropriate than others for a given context.

> 1st: **minable** ... 2nd: **piètre** ... 3rd: **pauvre** ... or something else?

Which adjective do you find most appropriate to use to express this idea?

Comment: Are you using “with just a measly one pair” (instead of simply “with just a measly pair” or “with just one measly pair”) in the English to emphasize that the hand’s unglamorous nature is the result of its having only one pair, regardless of the strength of that pair? If so, maybe it would be best to avoid adjectives/constructions in French that could imply that **the pair** was a low/weak one and try to find a way (as you did in English) to emphasize that the real issue is that **the hand** is weak because it only has one (sad/lonely) pair (?“avec juste une [seule/pauvre/malheureuse] paire”?).

Answer (score 5):

*Piètre* doesn't work well here (too formal and outdated) but *minable* and *pauvre* are fine:

> juste une pauvre petite paire
>
> juste une paire minable

Here are other suggestions:

> juste une petite paire de rien du tout
>
> juste une petite paire ridicule

Comment: So those four adjectives -- pauvre, minable, ridicule, de rien du tout -- generally match well with something representing a sum or an amount such as a salary, I take it?

Comment: Also: "minable" and "petite" are rather mismatched?

Comment: For a salary, *un salaire minable* and *un salaire ridicule* would best fit. *Un salaire de rien du tout* if fine too but not *un pauvre salaire*. *Petite paire minable* and *une minable petite paire* are possible.

Comment: @Alone-zee What do you mean "are rather mismatched" ?

Answer (score 1):

As a native French speaker I would not use any of these adjectives but rather say:

> ... juste une *misérable* paire.

*Misérable* is a false friend and doesn't mean sad but "really poor and weak". It can be applied to humans (c.f. [les miserables](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Mis%C3%A9rables)) but also to object/situations, where it often contains a bit of irony:

> Tu ne vas pas aller loin avec tes 3 misérables euros.

It is thus fine to express the weakness of a poker hand.